# Finding the series of of sequence $n(n-1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given the formula of sequence $$B_{n}=n(n-1)$$ Find the series $S_{n}$ of the sequence, such that $n \geq 0$.

What I did.

$$S_{n} = B_{0} + B_{1} + B_{2} + ... B_{n}$$
$$S_{n} = (0)(0-1) + (1)(1 - 1) + (2)(2 - 1) + ... + n(n-1)$$

Next thing is, I'm stuck. I have no idea how to progress from here. I spend quite some time to reduce this to a closed formula to no avail.

Comment: Observe that $$S_n = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} k(k - 1) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} (k^2 - k) = \sum_{k = 0}^n k^2 - \sum_{k = 0}^{n} k$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Know these two sums:

- $\displaystyle \sum_{k= 0}^n k = \dfrac{n(n + 1)}2$
- $\displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^n k^2 = \dfrac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}6$

Then we have:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
S_n &=& \displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^n B_k \\
&=& \displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^n k(k - 1)\\
&=& \displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^n (k^2- k)\\
&=& \displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^n k^2 - \displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^n k\\
&=& \dfrac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6} - \dfrac{n(n + 1)}2\\
\end{array}$$

Take out common factors, we have:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
S_n &=& \dfrac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6} - \dfrac{n(n + 1)}2\\
&=& \dfrac{n(n + 1)}{6} \left((2n + 1) - 3\right)\\
&=& \dfrac{n(n + 1)(2n - 2)}{6}\\
&=& \dfrac{n(n - 1)(n + 1)}{3}
\end{array}$$

Comment: How does the formula of summation $k^2$ came into being???

Comment: Notice that $$k^3 - (k - 1)^3 = 3k^2 - 3k + 1$$ The above formula can be proven with binomial theorem. Then we sum both sides from k = 1 to n. We get $$\sum k^3- \sum (k - 1)^3 = 3 \sum k^2 - 3 \sum k + \sum1$$ $$n^3 = 3 \sum k^2 - 3\frac{n(n + 1)}{2} + n $$ Then rearrange and factorise.